# Trying to wire 240 disconnect panel from 3 wire from main panel to 3 wire spa (2 hots and ground on both sides)

Tags: electrical

I’m wiring my used hot tub I bought which is a 240 volt total containing 3 wires, 2 hots and a ground. My feed from the panel is also 2 hots and a ground. How do I wire both sides to the gfci disconnect?

Comment: What make and model is your disconnect box, and your main panel for that matter?

Comment: Main panel is a Siemens and disconnect is a Homeline.

Comment: Is the breaker for this circuit in the main panel a full-width breaker, or half of a double-stuff/quadplex breaker? (i.e. does it have two fat handles on it or four skinny handles?)

Comment: In fact, can you post a photo of the breaker in the main panel that feeds this circuit?

Comment: It will be aSquare D Homeline 2 pole 50 amp breaker.

Comment: I just signed up to this so how to you add a photo. I will try to send a picture of the disconnect.

Comment: You should be able to hit edit (look for "share edit close flag delete" or something like that) on your post and then use the button that looks like a crude painting to upload a picture.  If you can't make that work, then upload the picture to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post a link in the comments, then we can edit it in

Comment: Ok give me a minute.

Comment: https://m.lowes.com/pd/Square-D-50-Amp-Non-fusible-Metallic-Spa/1017643

Comment: I was asking about the breaker *already in the main panel*, *not* the spa disconnect box

Comment: Have not bought it yet but this is it. https://m.lowes.com/pd/Square-D-Homeline-50-Amp-2-Pole-Standard-Trip-Circuit-Breaker/1078729

Comment: I take it you have two full-size open spaces in your panel?

Comment: Yes just curious how the wiring will connect in the disconnect box since there is no neutral other than the curly wire. I guess both grounds to the ground bar then ground the box to the neutral bar somehow.

Comment: ThreePhaseEel is asking about the breaker you plan to use in your Siemens main panel. **That would be a Siemens breaker.** You cannot use a Homeline breaker in a Siemens panel *even if it seems to fit*.  Homeline breakers are for use in your spa subpanel, but it already comes with a breaker.

Comment: Ok I will get a Siemens breaker. What would be the wiring diagram for the disconnect box without neutrals for the gfci to properly work?

Answer (score 1):

### When hooking up hot tubs, don't [fool around](http://www.cnn.com/2016/08/11/us/california-valley-fire-faulty-hot-tub/index.html)

It can [hurt people](https://www.pressdemocrat.com/news/4493945-181/remains-of-two-more-valley?gallery=4495798).  It can also [ruin hot tubs](https://www.sfgate.com/news/article/Harbin-Hot-Springs-ravaged-by-Valley-Fire-6503417.php).

### The lack of neutral at the hot tub box *might* be a problem

Your application doesn't need neutral at all.  (According to what you've said).

However, a couple weeks ago, we had a question about using American GFCI breakers in the Philippines, where some houses are wired exactly like your circuit there: two hots, no neutral, and a ground, theoretically in the middle between the two hots.   It turns out that some GFCI breakers actually need neutral on their input side - to power the GFCI mechanism *itself*.

It would not be legal in the US to "bootleg" that input neutral wire to the ground.  Bootlegging also wreaks havoc on any GFCIs that would be upstream, not that you would need any. That may be why TPE is asking about your panel breaker.  In his case, we counseled him to install a tiny autotransformer to create neutral from the two hots.  It worked.

Honestly, if it were me, I would take back that GFCI spa panel you bought, buy the correct Siemens GFCI 2-pole breaker for your *main* panel, and then get a simple/cheap non-GFCI subpanel or shutoff switch for this location.  That keeps the GFCI in the dry, warm inside, where it will last a lot longer.

But if you can't do that, you could try hooking it up without any neutral connected on the input side.  Maybe the GFCI will function correctly.  It is a spa panel after all, having no neutral on the input side is perfectly foreseeable since spas don't need neutral.  If it still doesn't function correctly, I would go talk to your AHJ, and see if they'll sign off on bootlegging netural *just for that GFCI device*.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a Siemens GFCI breaker in your main panel, and then a regular A/C pullout disconnect at the spa hookup

The problem with most North American 2-pole GFCI breakers is that they require a line-side neutral for their electronics package to run.  (I suspect this is a limitation of the underlying chipsets used, or at least the circuit designs commonly used with those chipsets.)  Since your wiring from the main panel to the spa disconnect lacks a neutral, you can't put the GFCI there.

*However*, Code doesn't care where the GFCI protection in a circuit is located, so one can put the GFCI in the main panel (using a QF2xxA where xx is the appropriate amp rating for your hot tub, given that your main panel is a Siemens and has 2 full-sized slots free), and then use a non-fused *pullout disconnect* rated for 60A to provide the disconnecting means in sight of the hot tub (these are quite cheap and readily available, more so than an equivalent non-fused safety switch).  This also gets the GFCI out of the weather -- while NEMA 3R boxes are generally decent at keeping rain and such out, they are *not* infallible/waterproof.

If you don't have space in your panel for this, then post photos of your main panel -- it may be possible to rearrange things or use double-stuff breakers to get the GFCI to fit, or install a subpanel to handle the overflow if other options don't work out.

### As to wiring the disconnect box

The disconnect box itself is wired simply, since the concerns about provisioning neutral to the GFCI are no longer present -- the line side hots go to the lugs on one side of the disconnect, the load side hots go to the lugs on the other side of the disconnect, and the grounds land on the disconnect's ground bar.